# c# visual studio 2015, Symantec deleting setup.exe file and preventing install

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, clickonce, symantec, setup.exe

I created a c# windows desktop application using Visual Studio 2015 to be used on other desktop computers at work. I used the "ClickOnce Deployment" it packages the application to be ready for instillation on another computer. I put the desktop application I created on a flash drive. Then I tested it on my computer and it goes through the set up (for requirements) and then installs the application file.

The problem I am encountering is when this same application is being install on another computer. The security program "Symantec" (symantec End Point) that is installed on other office computers deletes the setup file, and prevents the application from running or installing. Then I have to get the original files to copy the setup file back on the flash drive.  How do I get around this?  I think the security program is thinking that my application is malware or something.  The error message says something like, "Sonar.Rogue",

I have searched the internet and i haven't found a solution.  I

Comment: Our office also has Symantec Endpoint and our IT dept has setup certain policies.  Maybe they disallow _any_ **.EXE**s on USB sticks?  What happens if you put something else on there (perhaps a 3rd party non-.NET app exe) and try it?

Answer (score -1):

I am Chetan Savade from Symantec Technical Support team.

For software developers, authors, and Independent Software Vendors (ISVs), the Symantec Software White-Listing program offers an opportunity to reduce the possibility of false positives by adding your software to a whitelist that Symantec maintains of known good software. Please note that Symantec offers this service to reduce false positives, but cannot guarantee that false positives will not occur. Decisions made by Symantec are also subject to change depending on a variety of factors that include, but are not limited to, alterations in the software, distribution of the software, or vulnerabilities in the software to misuse by the publisher or others.
Refer this guide: Software developer would like to add his/her software to the Symantec White-List.
http://www.symantec.com/docs/TECH132220